# How do I import a variable from another Python script if the variable is only set within a define function?

Tags: python

So I have two scripts, a main one and a secondary one.  The main script is just mainly GUI code but I wanted one of the buttons to set a variable and then call in the second script.  The second script should then import the variable and continue on with it, however this isn't the case.

I tried presetting the variable outside the GUI code and theoretically it should change once the button is pressed but the second code simply imports the original variable.

```
from second import recognition
repeater = True
task = "placeholder"

def resume():
    while repeater:
        try:
            task = "hello"
            print(task)
            recognition()
```

```
def recognition():
    import first
    task = first.task
    print(task)
```

I thought that both print functions would print "hello", however the second print function prints "placeholder" instead.

EDIT: I've tried putting

```
global task
```

under

```
def resume():
```

```
while repeater:
```

and

```
try:
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let python know that you want to modify the global `task` - otherwise python will create a new local variable with name `task` inside `resume`

Adding a `global task` declaration inside the function should do the job

```
from second import recognition
repeater = True
task = "placeholder"

def resume():
    global task
    while repeater:
        try:
            task = "hello"
            print(task)
            recognition()
```

Comment: I tried putting global task there but it didn't seem to do much, also tried putting in under while "repeater:" and "try:".  It no longer calls me out for shadowing though.

Comment: Do you have a circular import in your scripts? That might be the issue

Comment: Ah yes, I do.  How would I fix this while keeping second being called by first and second taking a variable from first?

Comment: Um  you don't. Pull the variable away from both files and put it in it's own module.

Comment: Why don't you just use a parameter to your function? Your whole construct seems like pretty bad style imo

Comment: Yeah sorry, i'm kinda new to all this.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `global` keyword inside your function. This causes it to use the external variable.